# Howto assign a key in Eclipse Juno?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to assign a keyboard shortcut to "Build Project" in Eclipse Juno SR1. Seems to be a simple task but unfortunately it does not work.

I tried to assign several combinations, but if press the selected combination nothing happens. If I select the option from the menu, it works just fine.

What am I missing or is this a bug?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be hitting a bug in Juno.  There is a patch that can be used to work around the problem but no configuration workaround.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=383497